# My Lenovo tab 4 M 10 is frequently switching off its own. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: lenovo, power-on

Can anyone say how to resolve this?

Frequently it is turning off its own.

Comment: Considering the age of your tablet a bad battery would be a likely cause. You can check by connecting your tablet to a charger. If it does not power off when connected to the charger it is most likely the battery. or testing you should be able to enforce the "switch off"using e.g. a CPU benchmark app (increases power usage).

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons behind it. May be phone's battery is damaged. Or may be there is a background process which is never ending so in order to restore control phone turns it's all functions off.

You should probably take backup of your data and reset it.